# if-else statement syntax preference

Tags: php, syntax

I was wondering if there is any performance difference between the following 2 syntax of if-statement(similarly for other loops - while, for, foreach etc) :

```
 if(..) {...}
 else {...}
```

AND

```
if(..) : ...
else : ... 
endif;
```

Any advantages of using one over the other?

Comment: The latter is more commonly used in views because of its readability alongside markup. That's the only difference

Comment: I personally dont bother at all about PHP's performance. Use APC cache and PHP execution time is negligible as compared to a big SQL query or client side things.
Use echo only once or as less as possible. Keep on concatenating in a variable then echo at last.
While writing php code just focus on keeping it easy to read and modify later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You normally use the alternative syntax (`if (condition):` `endif;`) in views (templates) as it's easier to read amongst HTML. For example:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
<article class="item">
  <h1><?php echo $item->title; ?></h1>
</article>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Is easier to read than:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
<article class="item">
  <h1><?php echo $item->title; ?></h1>
</article>
<?php } ?>
```

Especially as you add more control structures such as `if`, `for` etc. If you use curly braces in HTML, it becomes harder to distinguish which closing curly brace belongs to which opening curly brace, whereas using the alternative syntax you know with `endif` you're looking for an opening `if:` statement.

Hope that helps.

Comment: from where do I get to learn such best practices, apart from friends/colleagues/discussion boards, coz those just happen in random :)

Comment: Various sources really. Just keep practicing, keep reading articles etc. There's no quick way. You can be a website developer for ten years and there'll still be more to know. That's the best thing about our industry.

Answer (score 3):

None.

The syntax styles are for only readability of the code.
Various organization may prefer various styles but there is no performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I only use the `if():` syntax if I'm mixing PHP and HTML:

```
<div class="stuff">
    <?php if($a === $b): ?>
        <span>Hello</span>
    <?php else: ?>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I think that looks nicer than using `if(){`, but in "normal" php code (not mixed with HTML), I use the `if(){` syntax.

```
<?php
if($a === $b){
    runThisCode();
}
else{
    otherCode();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No there is no performance difference only syntax. I personally use the first for core logic and use the second example within views or when php is interacting with or spitting out html. as i find it is easier to control final output without adding `\n` `\t`.

So no advantages apart from readability.