# Is it more efficient to declare a variable and change it if (something()) or should I use if and else?

Tags: php, syntax

Simple question, maybe a stupid question, but is it better to use

```
$var = 'value';
if (something()) $var = 'other value';
```

or

```
if (something()) $var = 'other value';
else $var = 'value';
```

?

And do I have to put something like `$var = null;` or `$var = 'value'` (in case something goes wrong with the following `if` and `else` statements) before the second variant for a nice code?

Comment: They are both so close in efficiency that it makes little difference performance wise. Choose whichever you feel is most readable and maintainable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [if-else statement syntax preference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535665/if-else-statement-syntax-preference)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @FDL! I thought maybe it's not nice code to assing a value to a variable and then replace it in the next line. I would personally prefer the second variant because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really makes no difference, and depends on your preference. My personal preference is to declare the the variable first. This is just so that I know the variable exists, regardless of the `if` statement.

Choose whichever comes naturally.

Comment: Thanks! As I said in the comments above, I would prefer the second variant because in the first variant you assing a value to a variable and then replace it in the next line (if the ´if´ statement is true). But good to know there's no big difference. I always wondered.